# Makefile seperate wildcald rule with more dependencies for files in a specific directory?

Tags: makefile

Say we have a project where using make, we create `.bar` files, then combine them into a `foobar` file for the final result.
We make each `.bar` file from a `.foo` file, and in the `foo` directory we also use a `.foobar` file which we also create using make.

I came up with this Makefile to do this:

```
default: all

%.bar: %.foo
        @echo generic build for $@
        @cat $< > $@

foo/%.bar: foo/%.foo foo/%.foobar
        @echo specific build for $@
        @cat $< > $@

%.foobar:
        @echo building $@
        @echo foobar > $@

foobar: foo/foo.bar bar/foo.bar
        @echo building $@
        @cat foo/foo.bar bar/foo.bar > $@

all: foobar

clean:
        rm -r foobar */*.bar

.PHONY: all clean
```

Then I set up an environment like this:

```
mkdir foo bar
touch foo/foo.foo bar/foo.foo
```

Now, running `make` I expect `foo/foo.bar` to be built using the second rule, and `bar/foo.bar` using the first.
Instead, I see the following output:

```
generic build for foo/foo.bar
generic build for bar/foo.bar
building foobar
```

Indicating that for both files, the first rule was used.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?
It seems to be related to having dependencies that don't exist yet compared to the other rule, since if I do a `make foo/foo.foobar` first then run `make` the second rule gets used for `foo/foo.bar`.
I want everything in the foo directory to specifically use the second rule with these dependencies, never the first one.

Comment: Then why don't you put a Makefile in the `foo` directory, so there is no ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

[Section 10.5.4 of the GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html) explains:

> a[n implicit] rule which can be satisfied without chaining other implicit rules
> (for example, one which has no prerequisites or its prerequisites
> already exist or are mentioned) always takes priority over a rule with
> prerequisites that must be made by chaining other implicit rules.

Pattern rules are implicit rules, and that is the effect you are observing.  To overcome it, you can either avoid using a pattern rule for building `.foobar` files, at least in folder `foo/`,  or remove the .foobar files from the prerequisite list for `.bar` targets in that folder.  Among the possible alternatives are:

- write a regular rule for building those `.foobar` files.  This will require designating all of them explicitly, but is not otherwise much different from what you're already doing.  For example,

  ```
  FOO_FOOBARS = foo/foo.foobar
  $(FOO_FOOBARS):
           @echo building $@
           @echo foobar > $@
  ```

  OR
- Remove `foo/%.foobar` from the prerequisite list of `foo/%.bar`.  Instead, use recursive `make` in that recipe to build the `.foobar` file when needed, something like this:

  ```
  foo/%.bar: foo/%.foo
          $(MAKE) $(<)bar
          @echo specific build for $@
          @cat $< > $@
  ```

Of those, I prefer the former.

Comment: In the actual code behind this the `.foobar` rule also had dependencies, so what ended up working based on your answer, but not entirely this, is using `define` to make a function with parameters that creates a `foo/%.bar` rule but instead of the wildcard, it uses the $(1) parameter to fill it in. After that, the function is run in a `foreach` with all `.bar`s and `eval`'d. This makes regular rules for each `.bar` and those get priority over the implicit ones.